# Update cascading to insert value to two different tables in database

Tags: cascading

I was trying to insert value for foreign which is auto generate in another table.

I found can do using update cascading I am looking insert many row for foreign keys example table `A` got product ID table `B` also got product ID but `B` also as is primary key which auto increment.how to code this using query or C#

Answer (score 0):

Ohk from the database here, you want to add the images in a new table using the `fk`. So a trigger won't work here. What you need to do is grab the `inser_id` after your `product` INSERT and then use that `id` to insert into `table b` as shown :

```
/*DATABASE TABLES*/

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `productID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `product_image` (
  `imageID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imageID`),
  KEY `product_images_ref_product` (`productID`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_images_ref_product` FOREIGN KEY (`productID`) REFERENCES `product` (`productID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


//Using C#
MySqlCommand comm = connect.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO product( `name`, `type`, `price`, `location` ) VALUES( '{0}', '{1}', {2}, '{3}' ); select last_insert_id();", 'Product 1', 'Product Type', 2.50, 'Here where I live' );

/* Grab the new product id */
int new_id = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());

/* 
    adding images to the table 
    here you can use a for loop to add more than one images.
*/
MySqlCommand comm = connect.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = string.Format( "INSERT INTO product_image ( `productID`, `location`, `image` )  VALUES( {0}, '{1}', {2} );", new_id, 'image_location', 'image_name' );

comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: If you don't mind giving an example of your table then we can help you an example. Would also need to know if your using MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc

Comment: table a is product : Product ID int (auto) ,Name , Type, price and location  table B Image for Products  ImageID int (auto) , Product ID (foreign key) reference product, image location, image . this two table if some user poser one product and many images images table must to update simultaneously. please help me to do this with some code or queries

Comment: Ohk from the database here, you want to add the images in a new table using the fk. So a trigger won't work here. What you need to do is grab the `inser_id` after your `product` INSERT and then use that `id` to insert into table `b`.

Comment: I have updated the answer for you. check it out and see if it helps. I'm assuiming that your using MySQL.

Comment: i am doing sql servr  i am sorry i didnt inform u thnx alot

Comment: Oh ok. its the same concept. Just need to grab the last insert id and you use that to add the images. The only difference would be the table creation. The c# code is the same.

Comment: i have problem on that i am keep trying i am really sorry

Comment: Also change `product( name, type, price, location )` to `product( name, type, price, location )` and the same goes for `product_image`. Or maybe it works with it still. Haven't done mssql in a while but it should work.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C gives a clear description on how to connect to a db using c#